# SQL Server Management Studio, error while logging in and not able to view the set-up jobs on the server

Tags: sql-server, indexoutofboundsexception

Am getting the below error while I logged into the SQL server from the remote location, and not able to view the jobs that were set-up

[image]

How to overcome this error?

Comment: May be you are using a earliest version of SSMS to connect with latest database instance. (eg Connecting from 2008/R2 Management studio to the instance 2012/2014).

Comment: What version of SQL Server Management Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error widely come when your SSMS version is lower than you accessed remote SQLserver version.

For example, you have `SQLServer 2008 R2` (Either only installed SSMS or full version) in your local and you access `Sqlserver 2012` or `SQLServer 2014`. While expanding the database object like table or procedure, you get the error.

The reason is, you can not edit/open the object when you open in lower version.

To resolve, you must installed the proper version or higher version of SSMS.

Comment: This is exactly true, I logged in from the higer version of the server and this is working fine !! Great !!

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your SQL Client to same as your SQL Server.

For your reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2459027